# click on photo and show corresponding item in list

Tags: jquery, html, for-loop, indexing

I am writing a new site for my math department of my University. I came across a problem when writing the page with info about our professors. I have designed a table with their photos and my idea was to show the user a box containing further details about that particular prof, when the user clicks on his/her photo. Here is how an info-div looks like in html:

*div with all the info-boxes about the profs*

```
<div id = "kartenliste">

<div class="w3-card-4 visitenkarte hidden" id="visprof1">
    *info about the first professor*
</div>

</div>
```

Here is what I tried in jQuery:

```
$("#proftable td").click(function() {
    var itemIndex = $("#profdiv").index(this) + 1;      
    $("#kartenliste .visitenkarte:nth-child(itemIndex)").show();
});
```

So I am trying to get the index of the the photo within the table and add 1 to it, so that it matches the index of the corresponding info-box in the list with all the professors. Apparently the variable itemIndex is not recognized as argument in the nth-child method.

Another idea was to use a for-loop:

```
$("#proftable td").click(function() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
        if ( i == $(this).index() ) {
            $("#kartenliste .visitenkarte:nth-child(i + 1)").show(); 
        };
    };
});
```

There are 22 professors in our department, hence the end value for i. However, this didn't work either...

Does anyone have a better idea? I would really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $("#kartenliste .visitenkarte:nth-child(" + itemIndex + ")").show(); //?

Comment: I was wondering too if maybe the variable is not recognized between the quote signs... I tried it, but still no result. Thanks for replying anyway!

Comment: It's me again :) You were actually right: the index value needs to be added outside the quotation marks. I read the documentation for index() more carefully and finally understood how it works. Here is the (now functional) piece of code: `var itemIndex = $("td").index(this);`  `$("#kartenliste .visitenkarte:nth-child(" + itemIndex + 1 + ")").show();`

Comment: Glad it was solved. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$("#kartenliste .visitenkarte").eq(itemIndex).show()`

Comment: Thank you, your idea works too. I just need to keep in mind that nth-child starts at 1 and eq at 0 :)

Comment: @TeodorChiaburu I am fishing for an upvote for some precious reputation points :-D

Comment: I can't vote yet, I have just subscribed to the site. I need some points too, to be able to give feedback by voting :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be adding an own attr to your td and then show this div with same id

```
<td own-attr="visprof1">Prof John</td>

<div id = "kartenliste">

<div class="w3-card-4 visitenkarte hidden" id="visprof1">
    *info about the first professor*
</div>

</div>
```

And then in jQ

```
$('td').click(function(){
   var showById=$(this).attr('own-attr');
   $('.visitenkarte#'+showById).show();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Clever idea, I see what you did there. Your code works too. So now I've got three options to choose from :)